# Java Min-Heap Implementing Priority Queue - Iteration

Tags: java, implementation, priority-queue

I'm trying to use this code to implement a Priority Queue. There are a number of questions regarding this implementation on the site, but given how many different ways you can write code to do essentially the same thing I am still at a loss after looking through a handful of other examples.

There are some missing lines in this code, but I am limited to editing only the four marked lines and so I find myself stuck on one particular aspect. I can't seem to understand how 'quantity' is incremented.

From my understanding main creates a new object of maxSize = 5. Then calls the insertItem method passing the value of 130. This should be placed into the root (I had put queArray[quantity] = item; into the first blank) at which point the insertItem method exits and is then called again with the next value. So at what point is 'quantity' incremented? Maybe I am missing something incredibly simple, or maybe there is another way of solving this that may not be apparent or known to beginners like me?

I would think you would want to increment quantity under the initial if statement, but that doesn't seem to be an option, so as far as I can tell the else statement can never be executed as quantity doesn't change. I know I am incorrect, but I don't know how, some help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    // array in sorted order, from max at 0 to min at size-1
    private int maxSize;
    private long[] queArray;
    private int quantity;

    public Main(int s) {
        maxSize = s;
        queArray = new long[maxSize];
        quantity = 0;
    }

    public void insertItem(long item) {
        int i;

        if (quantity == 0)
            __________; // insert at 0
        else
        {
            for (i = quantity - 1; i >= 0; i--) // start at end,
            {
                if (item > queArray[i]) // if new item larger,
                    __________; // shift upward
                else
                    // if smaller,
                    break; // done shifting
            }
            __________; // insert it
            __________;
        } // end else (quantity > 0)
    }

    public boolean PQEmpty(){
        return (quantity == 0);
    }

    public long removeItemPQ(){
        return queArray[--quantity];
    }

    public long peekMin(){
        return queArray[quantity - 1];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main thePQ = new Main(5);
        thePQ.insertItem(130);
        thePQ.insertItem(450);
        thePQ.insertItem(110);
        thePQ.insertItem(430);
        thePQ.insertItem(280);

        while (!thePQ.PQEmpty()) {
            long item = thePQ.removeItemPQ();
            System.out.print(item + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a style I'd recommend, but you could use `queArray[quantity++] = item;`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I hadn't thought of this either. It is certainly not the way I would do it, but there are plenty of other things I would have done if I were coding this from scratch, so it is worth a try. Now I just need to figure out if I can make that work.